# Qt 5.12.11 - How to use the Gtk2 theme

Tags: linux, qt, gtk, gtk2

When I create a Qt program (version 5.12.11) the theme does **not** look native.

```
qDebug() << QStyleFactory::keys();
```

Outputs:

```
("Windows", "Fusion")
```

Doing

```
QApplication::setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("gtk3"));
```

or

```
 QApplication::setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("gtk2"));
```

Does nothing.

I want to know how to achieve this, I have installed **qt5-style-plugins** and it made vlc player and qBitTorrent use the gtk theme but my app still doesn't use the native theme.

Comment: It seems that you have not installed it with the correct Qt. How did you install Qt 5.12.11 and how did you install qt5-style-plugins?

Comment: I installed qt with the online installer from the website and installed the qt5-style-plugins with apt.

Comment: That is the problem, run the online installer again and select package style-plugins

Comment: Thank you for your help but I fixed the issue by cloning [this](https://github.com/qt/qtstyleplugins) , building it and copying it to my Qt folder.